# Shift cells up if entire row is empty in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, row, openpyxl

I want the entire row to be removed(shift cells up) if there are no values in the entire row. I'm using Openpyxl.

My code:

```
for row in range(1, ws1.max_row):
  flag = 0
  for col in range(1, 50):
    if ws1.cell(row, col).value is not None:
      flag = 1

  if flag == 0:
    ws1.delete_rows(row, 1)
```

The rows are not getting deleted in the above case.

I tried using iter_rows function to do the same and it gives me:

`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`

```
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row = 1, max_col=50, max_row = ws1.max_row):
  flag = 0
  for cell in row:
    if cell.value is not None:
      flag = 1

  if flag == 0:
    ws1.delete_rows(row, 1)
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @CharlieClark: I don't think the flag is ever triggered. The rows were not getting deleted. I modified the code to use iter_rows and it's throwing me 'TypeError '>' not supported between tuple and int.

Comment: @CharlieClark: I have edited the original post with my other version using iter_rows.

Comment: You cannot pass a row into `delete_rows`. Also note, that if you delete a row while iterating over a worksheet you will skip the next row.

Comment: @CharlieClark: So I should get the index of the row each time the flag is set and then use a separate loop to delete all those rows right? But how do I solve the row skipping issue?

Comment: @CharlieClark: I found a solution, I have posted it as an answer, let me know if I can make any improvements to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a generic approach to finding and then deleting empty rows.

```
empty_rows = []
for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(max_col=50), start=1):

  empty = not any((cell.value for cell in row))

  if empty:
    empty_rows.append(idx)

for row_idx in reversed(empty_rows):
  ws.delete_rows(row_idx, 1)
```

Comment: This worked, but could you explain how it works? As I understand it, both idx and row starts at 1, then for each row, if there are empty rows, it gets added to the array which is finally reversed and then deleted. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: When you write `for idx,row in`, does both idx and row start from 1 ?

Comment: Please refer to the Python documentation for these builtin functions. An additional improvement would be to work out whether you have contiguous rows that need deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charlie Clark for the help, here is a working solution I came up with, let me know if I can make any improvements to it:

```
i = 1
emptyRows = []
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row = 1, max_col=50, max_row = ws1.max_row):
  flag = 0
  for cell in row:
    if cell.value is not None:
      flag = 1

  if flag == 0:
    emptyRows.append(i)

  i += 1

for x in emptyRows:
  ws1.delete_rows(x, 1)
  emptyRows[:] = [y - 1 for y in emptyRows]
```

Comment: You should use an enumerator do your counting. min_row and max_row will default to the supplied values. And if you delete the rows from the bottom you don't need to worry about row numbers changing.